# How can i create custom form on shopify?

Tags: shopify

i want create menu ( Service support ). when will be Customer click on service support menu, then it will be display on form like- ( name, email id, phone no, address, pin code ,invoice upload, invoice no, market place (drop down) , Description ) after that it will be submit and customer query will be display on shopify dashboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcwZT.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add any data to Shopify Dashboard. In stead you can follow below steps to achieve you goal.

1. Create custom APP ( which will display query data )
2. Create custom form using Shopify Liquid and send data to your app database using **[APP PROXY](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/app-extensions/online-store/application-proxies)**
3. Store Query Data in your DB and display it on your app dashboard.

Hope this will help.